# mvc advice needed on create/new view that is assigned to a model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, model

I'm pretty new in setting up mvc, please be patient..
So I have these two models

```
public class Promoter
 {
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}

    public ICollection<Event> AllEvents {get;set;}
 }

public class Event
 {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public date Date {get;set;}
    public int PromoterId {get; set;}

    public virtual Promoter Promoter {get;set;}
 }
```

And I have a controller Events

```
public class EventsController : Controller
{
   public ActionResult New()
   {
        return View()
   }
   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult New(Model model)
   {
       // do stuff to save the new Event related to Promotion
   }
}
```

so my problem is that, on the **New Action**, how do I make sure that the **New View** will be able to have an identifier on which Promoter it will be related to? I'm thinking hiddenfor that has the **PromotionId** so that when the Post gets called the Id will be there, but I will have to pass the Promoter Id when I call the **New** action?
Or do you think I should store the Promoter details in a cookie before going to that page?
Another thing to take note, the user will be authenticated and will need to be logged in to be able to access the **Promotion controller** (not shown in this thread) and then on that controller user can go to the said **Event Controller** which will have the New Action...

I hope that makes sense.
Need some advice, thoughts / ideas is very much appreciated.

THanks,

G

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're thinking right, you need to pass promotionId to the new action and action needs to pass it to the view. It is also possible through cookie, but I think action parameter is more convenient - because action parameter will be in url, so user can even bookmark it, send to another user, etc.